# Getting parse object for specific key in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I finally succeeded in saving an event to a specific user in Parse, but haven't quite figured out how to get them all out to populate a table view in a different view controller, a "My events" table view where a user can see the events they created.

How can I get the table view to populate with the image and title of the event? There is an event class with keys "image" and "title" but in order to get the events of the specific user I have to go through the user class and query for the "Events" key.

Sorry if this is a little confusing and there isn't much code to go off, if further explanation is needed that's not a problem. Thanks!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class CalenderViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate {

var eventsToAttend : [Event]? = []
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var responseObjects : [AnyObject]? = []

@IBOutlet weak var eventsTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.includeKey("Events")

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        self.responseObjects = objects

//            self.responseObjects = query?.findObjects()

    })


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    user?.objectForKey("Events")

    cell.textLabel?.text 

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

//        if let eventsToAttend = self.eventsToAttend {
//            return eventsToAttend.count
//        }

    return responseObjects!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse has already done the heavy lifting for you here, you can simply use their PFQueryTableViewController class and it will populate with your Event objects. See here for how to use it: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html
And a tutorial: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-in-a-table-view/

You can embed the PFQueryTableViewController into another view controller if you like. If you need to start doing special things like edits and deletes (or hiding) then it starts becoming better to roll your own implementation.

If you still want to try with the code that you started with, here is what you are missing:

1) In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, use the indexPath.row do get the correct Event object from the self.responseObjects (assuming there is only a single section).

2) Using the Event object you have gotten in step one, assign the title property to the cell.textLabel?.text.

3) Assuming that the Event.image property is a PFFile, you will need to load the PFFile async, in the callback create a new image from the bytes, then assign that new image to cell.imageView.image property.